# If a set is Hausdorff relative to one topology, can it be compact relative to a strictly finer topology?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> Let $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ be two topologies on set $X\neq\emptyset$ such that $(X, \tau_1)$ is Hausdorff and $\tau_1 \subsetneq \tau_2$. Can $(X, \tau_2)$ be compact?

My effort:

Suppose that $(X, \tau_2)$ *is* compact. Let the map $f \colon (X, \tau_2) \to (X, \tau_1)$ be defined by $$f(x) \colon= x \ \mbox{ for all } \ x \in X.$$
Then, for any open set $U$ in $(X, \tau_1)$, the inverse image $f^{-1}(U) = U$, which is open in $(X, \tau_2)$ as well. So $f$ is continuous.  Thus, $f$ is a continuous mapping of the compact space $(X, \tau_2)$ into (in fact, onto) the Hausdorff space $(X, \tau_1)$. So $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Therefore, if $V$ is an open set in $(X, \tau_2)$, then $f(V) = V$ is open in $(X, \tau_1)$ as well, showing that $\tau_2 \subset \tau_1$, which contradicts $\tau_1 \subsetneq \tau_2$. Hence $(X, \tau_2)$ cannot be compact.

Is the above proof correct?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: @M.L.Nguyen, do we need compactness of the coarser topology? Now look at the question at this URL: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328923/compactness-and-strictly-finer-topologies

Comment: @M.L.Nguyen, now also look at the question with this URL: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828324/finer-topologies-on-a-compact-hausdorff-space#comment2626840_828324

Comment: This is a special case of a general theorem: Any continuous surjection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a quotient map (and if it is a bijection then it is a homeomorphism).

Comment: @LeeMosher, then is there anything wrong with the above proof given by me?

Comment: @Brian M. Scott, can you please take a look at this post of mine and comment on how good my proof is?

Comment: @Saaqib: It’s fine: mine was the second upvote.