# Comparable topologies are equal if underlying spaces are Compact and Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing, compactness, separation-axioms

Since it considers the possibility of the topologies being same , I assume the underlying set is the same(Correct me if I'm wrong). So let $X$ be our set and $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are the two topologies that are comparable. So without loss of generality I can assume that $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$ and under both these topologies the space $X$ is both **compact** and **hausdorff**. So now I have to prove that $\tau_1 = \tau_2$. It suffices to show that $\tau_2 \subseteq \tau_1.$

Choose any arbitrary open set $U$ from $\tau_2.$ To show this is also open in $\tau_1.$ By compactness of $\tau_1$, $U$ has an open cover satisfying $$U\subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{k=n}V_k $$ where $V_k's$ are open sets in $\tau_1$.If not a proper subset then $U$ is already open in $\tau_1.$ So let's assume it is proper subset.

Then there exists a point $v_1$ in the RHS set that is not in $U$.By Hausdorff compactness we can find open sets $$A_1\cap B_1=\Phi$$ such that $$U\subset A_1 \\\text{and}\\ v_1\in B_1.$$
 Now $$ \bigcup_{k=1}^{k=n}(V_k\cap A_1)=W_1$$ is the new finite open cover of $U.$ If this is also not equal then we will find anothe $v_2$ with similar situation and this process goes on. Since the $W_i's$ always contain the $U$ and cannot be infinitely small so this process has to stop at one point and that is when we have arrived at an equation like $$U=\bigcup_{k=1}^{k=n}C_k$$ and $U$ is proved to be an open set in $\tau_1.$

Is this proof correct $?$ Please point out if there are mistakes and also tell how to correct those. I think I need to show that the process should stop after finite steps because infinite intersection of open sets may not be open but I do not know how to.

Thanks.

Comment: Right at the beginning you're misusing compactness. Compactness is *not* the statement "Every set has a finite cover," but rather "Every open cover of the whole space has a finite subcover."

Comment: @NoahSchweber : I know that. From any open cover I can find a finite subcover so there we have a finite open cover . Doesn't work?

Comment: It's not that the statement is false, it's that it's useless. Any set in *any* space has a finite open cover - namely, the whole space itself! $X$ is open in any topology on $X$. So that's not going to get you far in the proof.

Comment: @NoahSchweber : See my edit . What now?

Comment: Also, you haven't justified how the $A_1$ and $B_1$ exist, and you haven't explained why "this process has to stop at one point" (why can't the $W_i$s be infinitely small? and what exactly does that mean?).

Comment: Searching for [compact Hausdorff finer](https://www.google.com/#q=compact+hausdorff+finer) gives a few useful links: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828324/finer-topologies-on-a-compact-hausdorff-space, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328923/compactness-and-strictly-finer-topologies, https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Compact_Hausdorff_Topology_is_Maximally_Compact etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is not correct.  There is no reason that the sets $A_1$ and $B_1$ that you claim to exist must exist.  For instance, imagine $X=[0,1]$, $\tau_1$ is the usual topology, and $U=X\setminus \{v_1\}$.  I also don't at all follow why your process would need to end after finitely many steps.

As a hint that you're barking up the wrong tree, you haven't actually used compactness anywhere.  For any topology and any $U$, you could just take $n=1$ and $V_1=X$.  The power of compactness is not that there exists some finite open cover (which is trivial, you can always just take the whole space), it's that *no matter what open cover you start with* you can find finitely many of the sets which still cover.

I find this question easier to think about in terms of closed sets instead of open sets.  Try proving that any $\tau_2$-closed set must be $\tau_1$-compact, and then use the fact that a compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed.